# How to use glassfish with eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have been using Eclipse Java EE IDE for sometime now and have just downloaded Oracle's Java EE SDK. How can I add the glassfish to eclipse so that I can use the Java EE librarys?

Answer (score 0):

I think you actually want to install the Glassfish Tools.  I'm not sure the Java EE SDK includes a full server rather than the APIs you'd have when running on a server.

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools-kepler